# putting files paths that in specific dir in array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, directory

How should I put files paths in a StreamReader array that located in a specific dir C#?

I tried this code in different ways but I didn`t got nothing of what I need and I need one path

```
string fileName = "myfile.ext";
string path1 = @"mydir";
string path2 = @"\mydir";
string fullPath;

fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path1);
Console.WriteLine("GetFullPath('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path1, fullPath);

fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFullPath('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, fullPath);

fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path2);
Console.WriteLine("GetFullPath('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path2, fullPath);
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the expected result from the code above. Your question is totally unclear (at least for me)

Comment: This is very unclear, can you give an example of what you expect to get from those inputs? Also what does this have to do with `StreamReader`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but I suspect the current directory is not what you expect it is.  For example while running in the debugger, the current directory is the /bin/debug folder under your project directory.

Comment: you need to do some reading / research on the following `Directory.GetFiles` you can add these to a `List<T>` as well as a `strng[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you're trying to do, but maybe you want a list of files in a folder to a text file? If so, you could use this code:

```
    static void SaveFileListingToText(string folder, string outputTxtFilePath)
    {
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(outputTxtFilePath, files);
    }
```